# flag for no localization in iOS storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, localization, uistoryboard

In Xcode 6, I export a .xliff file with all strings in my iOS application (NSLocalizedString and storyboard strings). I have some UI strings (in UILabel/UITextview) that should never by translated though.

Is there a possibility to flag some UI elements in the storyboard as 'No Localization'?